# IndexOf with decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a bit of help ironing out a bug in a search form I'm working on.

I have a form of multiple checkboxes which submits via AJAX to PHP and returns a query string for use in deep-linking. The query string is used to check checkboxes on the page that appear in the query string.

The query string looks like this:

```
var returnedResults = #Size=35.5&Size=36&Colour=red&Material=leather
```

I have a form with a series of checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Size[]" id="35" value="35">
<input type="checkbox" name="Size[]" id="35.5" value="35.5">
<input type="checkbox" name="Size[]" id="36" value="36">
...
<input type="checkbox" name="Colour[]" id="red" value="red">
...
```

I am using jQuery's each function to loop through the checkboxes and check them if they appear in the query string:

```
$('input').each(function(){
  if (returnedResults.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
   // check the box
  }
});
```

This works fine for the most part but appears to return true for Size=35 when Size=35.5 is the only thing in the query string. ie. the checkbox with value=35 is checked when returnedResults=#Size=35.5

Is this a quirk of indexOf when dealing with decimals or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I would suggest using `.split('&')` on `returnedResults`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var returnedResults = "#Size=35.5&Size=36&Colour=red&Material=leather&Size=40.4";
var results = new Array();
results = returnedResults.split('&');
$.each(results, function(i) {
   var start = results[i].indexOf('=');
   results[i] = results[i].substr(start+1);
});
$('input').each(function(i){
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), results) > -1) {
      $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
  }    
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/7p3jJ/3/

What I did was parse the values from the query string using the [.split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and [.substr](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) methods. The values were then put into an array and then I used [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to check to see if the values exist in the array.

Answer (score 1):

It will return `true` because `indexOf` will only check if the string passed is present in the original string or not.

Your logic is not correct considering the scenario. You should parse the querystring and then check if the size is present or not.

Try this.

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


$('input').each(function(){
    if (getParameterByName("Size") == $(this).val()) {
     // check the box
    }
});
```

Note: The querystring not contain duplicate params you should first fix that.

Comment: does this work when the string contains more than one Size value?

Comment: Ideally the querystring should not contain duplicate param. The OP should fix that first.

Comment: Well, when using php you can send several values with a name like `Size[]`, and php makes them an array. This seems to be the case here, I believe.

Comment: I need there to be multiple params in the query string as multiple checkboxes of the same set (eg. Size or Colour or Material) are allowed. I use this indexOf technique with the other fieldsets because the values are all unique. I guess I should edit my question to ask what other method of testing a querystring for a certain value (or range of values) might be.